# Static classes C ++

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013, static

```
 #include"stdafx.h"
 #include"iostream"
 using namespace std;
 static class base{
 public:
    int i = 3;
 };
 int main(){
 base ob;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Please tell me, what do "static" in class declaration?

Comment: Please google first, e.g.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx

Comment: [That is **not** legal](http://ideone.com/WA5SJk).  It should not compile.  It may have originally been part of a variable declaraion, e.g.: `static class X{...} my_x_variable;`, but not in this code.

Comment: [It's invalid syntax!](http://ideone.com/aoQQRX) but may be hidden by other compiler errors.

Comment: What does it do? A compilation error.

Comment: @Borgleader Looks like the [`static class` error](http://ideone.com/HIV7zb) is hidden by the error appearing on `int i = 3;` actually.

Comment: @Trinimon: That link you provided does not help answer the OP's question, actually. Mainly because it covers valid uses of `static`, and the way the OP is using it is invalid. However, I can confirm that it does compile in Visual Studio 2013 (albeit with a warning that `static` is ignored)

Comment: Everything compiles, there are no compilation errors. Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @ЛеонтийХачуев: There is a warning though, isn't there?

Comment: With [this online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) I get: *main.cpp(6): warning C4091: 'static ': ignored on left of 'base' when no variable is declared*. Read your compiler output.

Comment: @ЛеонтийХачуев Visual Studio 2013 is as just fu***'n bad crap (as it  managed being in the last decade of VS versions seen), it seems. That's not standard c++, sorry!

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: this was just one link of thousands which explains what `static` might be good for (so I wrote _e.g._). My main message was: use any search engine before asking questions that can be easily looked up in the Internet ....

Comment: Thank, whether it is possible instead "const, volatile, extern, register " ? VS permits.

Comment: @Trinimon: And my main message to you was that any such search would have been futile, since most resources are not going to explain this peculiarity.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: then it's your chance to provide a clarifying answer ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Please tell me, what do "static" in class declaration? Thank."*

It actually does nothing, but is ignored by the compiler (with VS 2013 only as it seems). There's a warning issued about this:

```
source_file.cpp(9) : warning C4091: 'static ' : 
   ignored on left of 'base' when no variable is declared
```

See the live compiler sample [here please](http://rextester.com/ICLUE65017).

Comment: (A [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehkcz60.aspx) to their "warning" that their compiler may ignore nonsense keywords)

Comment: Actually, it's not just VS. Clang compiles it too.

Comment: No declarations about how crappy clang is? :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley _"... about how crappy clang is?"_ It didn't really have that much time, to really prove vs MSVC :-P ...